# Get HTML element ID that added later by Javascript

Tags: selenium

how can I get IDs of a html elements that added to page later by using javascript? JS changed the HTML contains after it's rendered thus selenium can't get the "just added" html elements.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get the element by Id - 
var element = document.getElementById(StringId);

insert new content -

element.innerHTML = newHTMLText;

append new content -

element.innerHTML += newHTMLText;

.
```